# About a complex number $z\in S^1$ fulfilling an inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be complex numbers, such that $\|a\|=\|b\|=\|c\|=1$.
 I have to show that there exists a complex number $z$, with $\|z\|=1$, such that:
$$\dfrac{1}{\|z-a\|^2}+\dfrac{1}{\|z-b\|^2}+\dfrac{1}{\|z-c\|^2}\le\dfrac{9}{4}$$

Comment: Let $a=\text{cis} \ A$, $b=\text{cis} \ B$, $c=\text{cis} \ C$, and $z=\text{cis} Z$. We have $z-a=(\cos A-\cos Z)+(\sin A-\sin Z)i$, so $$\| z-a \|^2=\cos^2 A+\cos^2 Z-2\cos A\cos Z+\sin^2 A+\sin^2 Z-2\sin A\sin Z=2-2(\cos A\cos Z-\sin A\sin Z)=2-2\cos(A-Z)$$

Comment: @NobleMushtak  seem usefull work,But then How to following work?

Comment: Actually, we can simplify this even more: $$2-2\cos(A-Z)=2(1-\cos(A-Z))=4\left(\frac{1-\cos(A-Z)}{2}\right)=4\sin^2\frac{A-Z}{2}$$ and then we can follow from [@JackD'Aurizio's argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1830886/307483) below.

Answer (score 1):

**A collection of hints.**

We may study the behaviour of the function:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} f(\theta) &=& \frac{1}{\|e^{i\theta}-e^{i\alpha}\|^2}+\frac{1}{\|e^{i\theta}-e^{i\beta}\|^2}+\frac{1}{\|e^{i\theta}-e^{i\gamma}\|^2}\\&=&\frac{1}{4\sin^2\frac{\alpha-\theta}{2}}+\frac{1}{4\sin^2\frac{\beta-\theta}{2}}+\frac{1}{4\sin^2\frac{\gamma-\theta}{2}}\end{eqnarray*}$$
over the interval $[0,2\pi]$. We may notice that for any $\varphi\in[0,2\pi]$ the measure of the subset of $[0,2\pi]$ for which
$$ \frac{1}{4\sin^2\frac{\varphi-\theta}{2}}\geq 1 $$
is exactly $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, hence for any $\varepsilon>0$ the measure of the subset of $[0,2\pi]$ for which
$$ f(\theta)\leq 3(1+\varepsilon)$$
is positive, so:
$$ \forall \varepsilon>0,\;\exists\, \theta\in[0,2\pi]:\quad f(\theta)\leq 3(1+\varepsilon).$$
Now you just need to improve a bit this argument.
We may try this approach: assume that $ABC$ is a triangle inscribed in a unit circle, with the $A$ vertex being associated with the greatest angle. If we take the symmetric of $A$ with respect to the centre of the previous circle, or **the midpoint of the $BC$-arc not containing $A$** $\phantom{}^{(*)}$, we get a reasonable $z$. Another good idea may be to exploit [Ptolemy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem) or a [circular inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry) centered at $z$ to send $A,B,C$ into three collinear points and deal with the sum of three squared distances:

[image]

> **(*)**: Just to restate it clearly, the inequality is trivial for obtuse triangles (the constant $\frac{9}{4}$ can be replaced by $\frac{3}{2}$). For acute triangles, if we take $z$ as the midpoint of the minor arc of the longest chord, $z$ fulfils the initial inequality, and such inequality is clearly optimal since equality is attained by the equilateral triangle.

Comment: Nice approach, +1  so this $\dfrac{9}{4}$ is not best constant? can replace the $3?$

Comment: @alreadyvhad: $3$ is greater than $\frac{9}{4}$: my inequality is sub-optimal.

Comment: so the best constant can replace $+\infty?$

Comment: No, the best constant is $\frac{9}{4}$ (attained by an equilateral triangle), but you need to refine my argument to prove your inequality with that constant.

Comment: I can't undestand ,can you detai  post your solution,  in $ABC$

Comment: @alreadyvhad: assuming that the angle in $A$ is the greatest, take $z$ as the midpoint of the $BC$ arc that does not go through $A$ and prove that such a $z$ fulfils the original inequality. It boils down to a simple trigonometry problem.

Comment: I think you use comments as well in response to a time when detailed as far as possible。agree me? Because Now I can't it, I don't known I was too stupid Or are you really didn't write clearly.I think the others did not understand So you don't have +1

Comment: I think others simply don't care. I didn't gave you a complete solution, but if you aren't able to take my collection of hints and come out with a full solution, I guess this problem is a bit above your level. That does not mean you are stupid, it simply means you have to work on details by yourself. Should I post a question asking for the equivalent and elementary version of this question through trigonometry?

Comment: Sometimes math is not completely to come also not necessarily can make according to clew, math many feel all seem to be all right, but in the end make it complete will encounter a lot of problems, but I still want to thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)=\frac{1}{|z-a|^2}+\frac{1}{|z-b|^2}+\frac{1}{|z-c|^2}$. The points $a,b,c$ divide the unit circle $|w|=1$ into three parts. We claim that we can take $z$ to be $d$ to be the midpoint of the longest part. Wlog that is $a$ to $b$.

[image]

If $a,b,c$ all lie on a semicircle, then $|c-d|>|a-d|=|b-d|\ge\sqrt2$, so $f(d)<\frac{3}{2}<\frac{9}{4}$. So we can assume the difference between the arguments of $a,b$ is less than $\pi$.

The distance between two points on the unit circle whose arguments differ by $\theta$ is $2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$. For the points $a,b$ we have $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{3}+2x$ for some $0<x<\frac{\pi}{6}$. So the argument difference between $a,d$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}+x$. Hence $|a-d|=|b-d|=2\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{x}{2})$.

Since the argument difference between $a,c$ and between $b,c$ is less than $\theta$, the argument of $c$ differs by at most $3x$ from the antipodal point to $d$, so the argument difference between $d,c$ is at least $\pi-x$. Hence $|c-d|\ge2\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{3x}{2})$.

So we are home provided $$\frac{2}{\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{x}{2})}+\frac{1}{\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{3x}{2})}\le9$$ for all $0<x<\frac{\pi}{6}$. The first term decreases from 8 at $x=0$ to 4 at $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$. The second term increases from 1 at $x=0$ to 2 at $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Differentiating we get $-2\cot(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{x}{2})\csc^2(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{x}{2})+3\sec^2\frac{3x}{2}\tan\frac{3x}{2}$. Both $\cot$ and $\csc$ are decreasing over the range, so the first term is increasing. Both $\sec$ and $\tan$ are increasing over the range. So the derivative is increasing. At $x=0$ it is $-8\sqrt3$. So it has at most one stationary point in the range, which would be a minimum. Hence its maximum value must be at one of the two endpoints. Those are 9,6. So the maximum is 9 (corresponding to $a,b,c$ forming an equilateral triangle), as required.

Comment: Nice.@almagest,I have understand your solution!

Comment: @alreadyvhad: so you got the second part. (+1) to almagest, but I still think you lost something by not attempting it by yourself.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Now you make me feel bad. :( I can only plead that I thought it was a relatively hard problem and that someone on his first day might need something more direct than you were giving him. But +1 for your efforts to lead him on.

Comment: @almagest   Where do you come from, I feel your math very well Thanks

Comment: I live in London, UK.

Comment: Thanks, and we can consider this problem In general? if $|z_{1}|=|z_{2}|=\cdots=|z_{n}|=1$,if there exist $|z|=1$ such $\sum\dfrac{1}{||z-z_{1}||^2}\le C_{n}$,find the best $C_{n}$?

Comment: If you want to propose that, I suggest a fresh question! It could be much harder, I have not thought about it. But there are similar problems for which little is known in the general case except some bounds.

Comment: Thanks,I have post it ， For the first time know this site don't know a lot of rules, please forgive me